# Difference between using `? super` in parameter and variable

Tags: java, generics, super, bounded-wildcard

I thought I'd figured out generics with `super`. But I must be completely wrong:

With this simple example:

```
class Animal{}
class Dog extends Animal{}
```

This code works fine because we are passing in a super class of Dog:

```
static void addThis(ArrayList<? super Dog> a) {
    a.add(new Dog());
}
...
ArrayList<Animal> dogs=new ArrayList();
addThis(dogs);
```

However, what I don't understand is I thought this is the same thing:

```
ArrayList<? super Dog> dogs2=new ArrayList();
dogs2.add(new Animal());
```

But it fails to compile. What is the difference between the two?

---

By the way, I'd like to sneak in another question. Is there any difference between

```
// This...
ArrayList<Animal> dogs=new ArrayList();
// ... and this?
ArrayList<Animal> dogs=new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

Given type erasure removes it at compile time I figure it's the same thing as the compiler is checking the reference type. Is this correct?

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I rolled back your edit, so that the answers would make sense. Feel free to ask a new question if you still have doubts about anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not at all the same thing.  In one case you're adding a `Dog`, in the other case you're adding an `Animal`.

In both cases you only *know* that `Dog`s are allowed, so the second case fails.

To answer your second question, there *is* a difference, and you should always use the second version.  (In Java 7+, however, you can request the compiler to infer the generic type for you by writing `new ArrayList<>()`.)

Comment: Sorry, I completely messed up my question. My mind was in a different place due to getting confused. The real question was about, well, what I've updated it to (I didn't expect an answer so soon!), i.e. I thought super meant The item or a supertype can be added.

Comment: `? super Dog` means there is _some unknown_ superclass of `Dog` which you're restricted to.  That could be `Dog` itself, which would forbid `Animal`, or it could be `Object`, in which case you could add anything.  But the only thing you _know_ is allowed is `Dog`.

Comment: Ah, I see the light now. I was thinking the ?super extended to what you put in it as well. So as long as what I pass in is the same or super type then we know we can add any subtype. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dog is an Animal so you can cast the `ArrayList<? extends Dog>` to `ArrayList<Animal>` but you can't go the other way since an Animal is not necessarily a Dog.

eg:

```
public class Cat extends Animal{}
```

Since this wouldn't make sense:

```
ArrayList<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();
dogList.add(new Cat());
```

You can't add an animal to the Dog list because the animal can be a cat.

This is an example of Java Type safety.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, `List<? super Dog>` is a list of objects which have `super`(parent) as `Dog`, NOT a list of objects which are `super` of `Dog`

Comment: Seems you put what I was thinking at the same time (I added a comment above): I was thinking the ?super extended to what you put in it as well. So as long as what I pass in is the same or super type then we know we can add any subtype. Thanks.